# Apache 2.4.3 (with XAMPP 1.8.1) not starting in windows 8

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, port

Just got XAMPP 1.8.1 installed on my Windows 8 PC, this version includes packages mentioned below:

```
Apache 2.4.3
MySQL 5.5.27
PHP 5.4.7
phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2
FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.41
Tomcat 7.0.30 (with mod_proxy_ajp as connector)
Strawberry Perl 5.16.1.1 Portable
XAMPP Control Panel 3.1.0 (from hackattack142)
```

When I launched and tried to start Apache, it gave following error:

```
12:04:41 PM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
12:04:41 PM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
12:04:42 PM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
12:04:42 PM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:04:42 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:04:42 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:04:42 PM  [Apache]   Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
12:04:42 PM  [Apache]   and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

After that I checked error.log, it was empty so no help from there.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

So here is the solution for this:

I check port `80` used by Skype, after that I changes port to `81` and also along with that somewhere i read this error may be because of SSL Port  then I changed SSL port to `444`. However this got resolved easily.

One most important thing to notice here, all the port changes should be done inside config files, for http port change: **httpd.conf** for SSL **httpd-ssl.conf**. Otherwise changes will not replicate to Apache, Sometime PC reboot is also required.

**Edit: Make Apache use port 80 and make Skype communicate on other Port**

For those who are struggling with Skype, want to change its port and to make Apache to use port 80.

**No need to Re-Install, Here is simply how to change Skype Port**

```
Goto: Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection
```

There you need to `uncheck` **Use port 80 and 443 as alternative for incoming connections.**

That's it, here is screen shot of it.

[image: Changing Skype Port]

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the same problem for me. I had just reinstalled Skype and so this explained a lot!

Comment: If problem still persists after doing above steps,just restart the computer and it will be solved.

Comment: never expected this to work. but it worked, nice one

Answer (score 21):

I had the exact same error.

It was because i didn't run setup_xampp.bat

This is a better solution than going through config files and changing ports.

Comment: I notice that this was happening for me as, however, I couldn't run setup_xampp.bat manually either.

Answer (score 19):

This problem may occur due to apache not getting required port (default is `80`).

The port may be being used by other services.

For example: Skype also has default port `80`.

Installing Skype and Apache both on same machine will cause conflict and hence Apache will not start.

Either, you change Skype port or change Apache port as described in following steps:

Change the ports of Apache and it will work for you.
Go to httpd.conf

**How to change port for Apache:**

Search for:

> ServerName localhost:80

Change it to:

> ServerName localhost:81

Also Search For:

> Listen 80

Change it to:

> Listen 81

If you have created any virtual hosts, change the ports there also.
Then restart your apache.

Comment: Yep, this is indeed the right way to go about it. +1

Comment: +1 . This was the one that fixed it for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, but I understand the **VMware service** is the problem. VMware host service and Apache service conflict together.

**To Solve it** »
Run your task manager » in services tab find VMwareHostd » then right click and stop it » every thing have been solved.

Answer (score 4):

Enter services.msc and shutdown anything SQL you have running.
The SQL server might be taking over the port.

Comment: How can SQL (be it MS SQL Server (1433) or MySQL(3306)) block (in your language take over)  apache port???

Comment: hmm, thanks, it seemed in my case, SQL Server did took over the ports and when I stopped them, Apache server started.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and error, I tried changing the ports for http port from 80 to 81 and ssl port from 443 to 444 but still received the same error so I reverted the ports to default and **ran setup_xampp.bat** which solve the problem in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Skype is usually the culprit because it uses port 80  by default. Just close it or uncheck "Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections" under tools > options... > advanced > connection and then restart Skype.

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually edit the 2 text files (httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf) using the Config button for Apache to run and change in notepad from 80 > 81 and 443 > 444

Using the Xampp UI config manager doesn't save the changes into Apache.

Comment: I have the Skype app on Windows 8, which apparently doesn't want to let the user do anything useful. AFAIK, there's no straightforward way to set the Skype port numbers. I edited httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf and everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

change 80 to 81 and 443 to 444 by clicking config button and editing httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.congf. Now you can Access XAMPP from 127.0.0.1:81

Answer (score 0):

An error in your httpd.conf or other Apache config files will cause this. Revert httpd.conf *et al* to the pristine, installer versions and see if Apache runs again.

(I tried Skype and other suggestions here, no luck, but logs [XAMPP > Apache > Logs button] showed that it ran once when first installed. That was the giveaway.)

Likely errors:

- Did you edit with a Windows text editor that changes line endings to non-Unix? (Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886185/eclipse-and-windows-newlines).)
- Missing or invalid DSO files (.so)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and then I ran "apache_start.bat" the error in german told me there was a problem with line 51 in httpd-ssl.conf which is

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
```

What I did was comment lines 163 (ssl module) and 522 (httpd-ssl.conf include) in httpd.conf;
I don't need ssl for development, so that solved it for me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you did exactly? In my case in line no 522 in httopd.conf file I get the line <IfModule proxy_html_module> .  And where to get ssl module file so that I wud search line no 163? What is exactly in line no 51 of httpd-ssl.conf file in your case, because in my case it's shows a different text.

Comment: Line 163 of httpd.conf was enabling the ssl module. But that's so long ago I don't use windows anymore.
(I really recommend rolling release distros of our beloved gnu/linux os... I'm using an arch based one called Apricity OS, it's great)