# Eclipse PyDev, change end of line character

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, pydev

I recently started building some python scripts to run on an Ubuntu server to be called from Apache2 server(Running this on Beagle Bone Black/Ubuntu).  I kept getting internal server error and had no idea why.  Turns out it was the end of line characters assigned by default by PyDev/Eclipse.  It was using CRLF as the end of line which Unix OSs do not recognize and caused nasty crashes and a lot of frustration.  I wanted to find out if there is a setting for PyDev or Eclipse to change the end of line character to only LF as needed by Unix based OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [Eclipse and Windows newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886185/eclipse-and-windows-newlines)

Go to preferences, and on General->Workspace settings you'll find this setting.

Comment: This changes it for all files, not just PyThon files