# getpass() appending carriage return at the end (in eclipse)

Tags: python, eclipse, getpasswd

When I run the following code in eclipse, getPass returns a string suffixed with a carriage at the end.

However, when I run the same code in command prompt it runs without any problem.

```
import paramiko
import getpass

userPwd = getpass.getpass()
print ('You have entered ',userPwd)

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('ese.rnd.sanl.se', username='abc', 
    password=userPwd)
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command("ls")
data1=stdout.read().splitlines();

for line in data1:
    print (line)
```

Output (Eclipse):

```
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password: Mypassword@123
('You have entered ', 'Mypassword@123\r')
```

Output (Command Prompt):

```
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password: Mypassword@123
('You have entered ', 'Mypassword@123')
```

Can anyone explain this ambiguity?

Thanks!!

Comment: Might be that the eclipse shell adds a character return while your normal shell doesn't.

Comment: But when I replace getPass() with raw_input it works perfectly fine. Why doesn't it add extra character at the end in case of raw_input?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect eclipse is set to use windows newline i.e. '\r\n'.  You will want to set it to use the UNIX new line ('\n')

Basically, this means that the python method 'getpass()' is chopping the final character in the buffer.  Since you are giving two characters, it is missing the \r.

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886185/eclipse-and-windows-newlines) to see how to modify this option.